# Angular 5: Prevent to reload tab content when changing between tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, material-design, angular-material

I'm using Angular 5 to develop an admin backend based on Material Design. One of the views is tab based with the first tab containing an iframe. However, when changing between the different tabs and then navigating to the first tab holding the iframe, the iframe is reloaded. The goal is to switch between the tab without reloading its content. How can I achieve this?

**room-details.template.html**

```
<mat-card class="p-0">
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Vorschau">
      <mat-card-content class="mt-1">
          <iframe src="https://......" width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Einstellungen">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p class="mt-1">Sprache</p>
        <mat-radio-group fxLayout="column">
          <mat-radio-button [style.marginBottom]="'.5rem'" value="1">Deutsch</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button [style.marginBottom]="'.5rem'" value="2">Englisch</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button [style.marginBottom]="'.5rem'" value="3">Französisch</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
        <mat-divider class="mb-1 mt-1"></mat-divider>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</mat-card>
```

Currently the logic is not yet implemented in room-details.component.ts.

Comment: show your code and your tries ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

When your route a component, once you leave it, you actually destroy them.

This means, when you come back to it, you are creating it again, thus loading all of its HTML (including your IFrame).

Maybe you could try with a non-routed component (I don't remember if tabs keeps the component instance or destroy it, but I would say they keep it), or attach your IFrame to the router-outlet above, and position it as absolute (and don't display it when the route isn't matching the one you want).

I know it's a lot for just not reloading a component, but iframes are old, and not so widely used !

Comment: or just use regular divs that you show/hide with `[hidden]="condition"`. NOT `*ngIf` that will also destroy and re-create the divs.

Comment: Yeah but in that case, it is redundant, because tabs are already handling it. This would be the second option after non-routed tab I tink, before the absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

As there is not straightforward way to do this, we can use a simple work around. The idea is to just display the title using mat-tab but the content comes from another section which will be right under the tab HTML component (like a mat-grid used below). This content visibility will change based on the tab selection.

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value"
               (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)"
               (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
 <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index">
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          {{tab.label}} &nbsp;
          <i class="icon XXX" (click)="removeTab(index)"></i>
      </ng-template>

  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<mat-grid-list>
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index"
        [style.display]='tab.active? "inline" : "none"'
        [style.position]='tab.active? "static" : "absolute"'>

    <iframe id="tabframe-{{tab.id}}" [src]='tab.url' ></iframe>

</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

And, in the tab.component.ts file, use the tabChanged Event that fires whenever there is a tabchange as per the HTML above

```
export class TabbarComponent implements OnInit {

  tabs = [];
  tabChanged($event) {
    console.log($event);

    for (const ttab of this.tabs)  {
      ttab.active = false;
    }
    this.tabs[$event.index].active = true;
  }
}
}
```

And tab.ts file

```
export class Tab {
  label: string;
  url: SafeUrl;
  active: boolean;

  constructor(label: string) {
      this.label = label;
  }

}
```